# magento 2 error factory class does not exist

Tags: magento2, php, custom

This is my block class for form

**Smartshore/Subscription/Block/SubscriptionForm**

```
namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Block;

class SubscriptionForm extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_subscriptionLoader;  

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\SubscriptionFactory $_subscriptionLoader

    ) {
        $this->_subscriptionLoader = $_subscriptionLoader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getSubscriptionBy($id)
    {
        return $this->_subscriptionLoader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

**Smartshore/Subscription/view/frontend/layout/subscription_index_add.xml**

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>New Subscription</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Smartshore\Subscription\Block\SubscriptionForm" name="subscriptionform.add" template="Smartshore_Subscription::form.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In my template(**Smartshore/Subscription/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml**) I'm using `$this->getSubscriptionBy($id);`

But I'm getting two errors:

```
Invalid block type: Smartshore\Subscription\Block\SubscriptionForm
Class Magento\Catalog\Model\SubscriptionFactory does not exist
```

What is causing the errors here?

Comment: Please give with full File Path from Magento 2 & Which files u have created

Comment: Please see my edited question @AnkitShah

Comment: Please check ur etc folder's `module.xml` & `di.xml` if u have. Find in whole folder `Magento\Catalog`

Comment: have you created Subscription model if yes then post model code and path of model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error comes from the `__construct` method in your block (di):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\SubscriptionFactory $_subscriptionLoader

) {
// ....
```

There is no class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\SubscriptionFactory` in the Magento. You should check what model you are trying to use in your block. Possible, it should be your own model (the corresponding model of your module)?

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem solved.
Please refer to the block class, I was having the problem of factory Class path

Smartshore/Subscription/Block/SubscriptionForm

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Block;

class SubscriptionForm extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_subscriptionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory $subscriptionCollectionFactory,
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Smartshore\Subscription\Model\SubscriptionFactory $_subscriptionLoader,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_subscriptionLoader = $_subscriptionLoader;
    }

    public function getSubscriptionById($id)
    {
        return $this->_subscriptionLoader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```